# SSMS output delimited files with headers

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way using SSMS or other tool to output about 600 tables from a SQL Server database. The catch is they need to have column headers.
Basically I need to dump 600+ tables with a bar '|' delimiter, and they need to all have column names in the first row.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Im trying to get that information now. At the moment I do not know the version, but would guess its 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right you should be able to use the command line [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) tool to export data together with headers. Something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d YourDatabase
-E -Q “SELECT * FROM YourTable” -o “CSVData.csv” -W -w 1024 -s”|”
```

You'll have to look into the options to get them right.